# How to make two lists interchangeable, and when selection complete save dropped

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, sorting, drag-and-drop

I am using **jQuery** and specifying two `selectors` together. Then I try to refer each variable in this code:

**`UL_HeadersToOmit`** - is the list to choose from

**`UL_dropedCols`** - is the list to be passed as reference to next function or "*stage*"

```js
$('#next').click(
function () {

    var dropblUL = $('#UL_dropedCols li');
    alert(dropblUL.length);
});



$('#UL_dropedCols, #UL_HeadersToOmit')
    .sortable({
               connectWith: '#UL_HeadersToOmit, #UL_dropedCols'
             })
    .droppable({

            drop: function (event, ui) {
                     var curUL = $(this);
                    //.. now till here from what i could see in tests 
                    // drop is connected to the first  #dropedCols
                    // so if i wanted to specify same thing for second HeadersToOmit
                   // how will i do it ?

                  }
            });
```

I could see people at tutorials connecting

```
$(obj).draggable().droppable().sortable()
```

I guess this is ok if their all referring one object, but how will you refer two?

**my goal** is naturally : to save what user selected
...meaning whats left on `#UL_dropedCols`,
at the end of the selection (keeping in mind user is playing between them-two, back and forth )
then clicking next.

### update

http://jsfiddle.net/rhW7C/46/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/rhW7C/46/

Comment: a `sortable` item already is a `draggable` and it's container is already `droppable` . Really not clear what you are wanting to do. Suggest you supply some html in a jsfiddle.net demo along with explanation that ties to the html

Comment: I'm under the impression that everything that's matched in the selector (assuming it's not filtered out by traversal or filter methods) is available throughout the whole chain of chained jQuery methods. But I don't understand the problem you're having; could you maybe take some time to clarify?

Comment: @DavidThomas i might be using it wrong, as it's my first time, though question is how to save results of final selection

Comment: You want to save which elements are in which lists once sorting is completed?

Comment: @DavidThomas see link mr' Thomas exactly as you said in your last comment ,yes

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was missing the `receive` event as seen below.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var results = [];

    $('#UL_dropedCols, #UL_HeadersToOmit').sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        connectWith: '#UL_HeadersToOmit, #UL_dropedCols',
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            var draged = ui.item.attr("id");
            results.push(draged);
        }
    });

    $('#next').click(function() {
        var RLength = results.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < RLength; i++) {
            alert(results[i]);
        }
    });

});
```